# What is the "use" item in Sam and Max

Tags: sam-and-max-hit-the-road

This question bothers me since I was a kid.
In Sam and Max - Hit the Road, what is the green thing in the "use" icon?
[image]
Is it a duck? Is it a toy?

Comment: It's a useful item, apparently. Sorry, not a useful comment ;p

Comment: @RedriderX facepalm.. \:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a cartoonish [Stress Toy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_ball), sort of like [this guy](http://www.officeplayground.com/Wobbly-Stress-Toy-P1769.aspx). You squeeze them and it looks like their eyes pop out. I know I've seen them styled just like that in other cartoons, so it might be a running gag I'm unaware of.

Answer (score 4):

I believe it is a Bug Out Bob. However I don't think you can actually buy them in green :(

Comment: Avoiding copyright issues, probably.

Answer (score 0):

It is a [toy known variously as Panic Pete, Jo-Bo, Obie, The Martian Popping Doll, The Martian Popping Thing, Popping Martian, or Bug-Out Bob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panic_Pete). It has been around since around 1950.

Most likely chosen because it's an iconic but somewhat old-fashioned American toy, and the game is full of iconic Americana.